# Mongoose slow queries with MongoDB Atlas

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I am experiencing some slow queries with Mongoose using MongoDB Atlas. It is not a free shared cluster.

I have a pagination function that looks like this:

```
export const Pagination = async ({ model, page, limit, populates }: props) => {
    const p: number = Array.isArray(page) ? parseInt(page[0]) : parseInt(page)
    const l: number = Array.isArray(limit) ? parseInt(limit[0]) : parseInt(limit)

    const startIndex = (p - 1) * l
    const endIndex = p * l

    const items = await model.find().limit(l).skip(startIndex).populate(populates)

    const amountOfDocuments = await model.estimatedDocumentCount()

    const maxPage = Math.ceil(amountOfDocuments / l)

    const results = {
        pagination: {
            maxPage: maxPage,
            current: page,
            next: endIndex < amountOfDocuments ? p + 1 : null,
            previous: startIndex > 0 ? p - 1 : null,
        },
    }

    return {
        results,
        items,
    }
}
```

And for instance when I fetch all documents in a collection where there is a total of 170 documents I get a 1000ms response time in average.

Adding populate on top of this adds double the amount of time so 170 documents is a 2s response time. Total size is 316KB without populate and 1202kb with populate.

Also the populated collection is a document containing only 12 key/values with booleans and short strings (max 50 in length).

It feels very slow but I don't know what the response time should be. I am running the API calls locally to the remote mongoDB atlas cluster.

I am using Next.JS

Comment: Where did you do this time calculation? Using code?

Comment: I made API calls using Insomnia. The server is locally so there should only be minimal delay from the server-side.

Comment: I also use mongodb locally and the calls using a local mongodb instance is 100ms with populate, size 1351KB. As soon as I connect to remote mongoDB it increases to 2000ms. Obviously I can expect some delay but using the closest server MonogDB Atlas provides the increase from 100->2000ms is a lot in my opinion.

Comment: Check the network latency